# PowerShell copy latest file in recursive folders

Tags: powershell, recursion

I have this simple cmdlet that correctly copies files and folders to a second directory:

```
Copy-Item -Path 'G:\xyz\Test\A' -Recurse -Destination 'G:\xyz\Test\B\'
```

However I am unable to tweak it to only copy the *latest file* in each folder within its folder (i.e. also copying the folder structure). I have written the following, but this doesn't copy folder names and does not go down all the hierarchies of sub-folders.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'G:\xyz\Test\A' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'G:\xyz\Test\A' -File -Recurse |
     Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1 | 
    Copy-Item -Destination 'G:\xyz\Test\B\'
}
```

Could someone please identify my errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach of collecting the directories first then iterating through them to retrieve the files.

```
If ( -not (Test-Path -Path "G:\Test\B")) {
  $Null = New-Item -ItemType "Directory" "G:\Test\B"
}

Get-ChildItem -Path 'G:\Test\A' -Directory -Recurse | 
   
   #Sort to insure dirs are created shortest to longest
   Sort-Object FullName |
   ForEach-Object {
     $DestPath = $($_.FullName).Replace("`\Test`\A","`\Test\`B")
     If ( -not (Test-Path -Path "$DestPath")) {
      $Null =  New-Item -ItemType "Directory" "$DestPath"
     }
     Get-ChildItem -Path "$($_.FullName)" -File |
     Sort-Object LastWriteTime |
     Select-Object -Last 1 | 
     Copy-Item -Destination "$DestPath"

   }
```

Comment: With many folders, would "collecting the directories first then iterating through them" be a bit risky in terms of memory?

Comment: Well you'd need a lot of very longdirectories

Answer (score 1):

First error is that you don't pass the current directory from the outer `Get-ChildItem` to the inner one. The inner one currently always loops over the same sub directory.

Also, when you copy individual files in a `Get-ChildItem` pipeline, you have to build up the destination path on your own, in order to keep the relative source directory structure:

```sh
$source = 'G:\xyz\Test\A'
$destination = 'G:\xyz\Test\B\'

# Set base directory for outer Get-ChildItem and Resolve-Path -Relative
Push-Location $source  
try {
    Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach-Object {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Fullname -File -Recurse |
            Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1 | 
            ForEach-Object {
                # Make the current file path relative to $source
                $relativePath = Resolve-Path $_.Fullname -Relative

                # Build up the full destination file path
                $destinationFullPath = Join-Path $destination $relativePath
                
                # Create destination directory if not already exists (-force)
                $null = New-Item (Split-Path $destinationFullPath -Parent) -ItemType Directory -Force

                # Copy the current file
                Copy-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Destination $destinationFullPath
            }
    }
}
finally {
    Pop-Location  # Restore the current directory
}
```

- `Resolve-Path -Relative` makes the given path relative to the *current* directory. In order to get paths relative to the source directory, we set the current directory to the source directory path using `Push-Location`.
- The `try` and `finally` blocks make sure the current directory is restored even in case of a script-terminating error (exception).

Comment: Well you'd need a lot of very long directories to cause memory problems. A single GB of memory will hold approximately 6,500 paths of 160 bytes each.